# How can I sent a variable from a controller to a view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to sent the value of my variable **$username** from my controller to my view.

---

## Controller

I sent it over in the bottom of my controller like this :

```
return Redirect::to('/')
    ->with('error','Username/Password Wrong or account has not been activated !')
    ->withInput(Request::except('password'))
    ->with('username', $username )
    ->withErrors($validator);
```

**Note** : $username

---

## View

Somewhere in my homepage with the url of `/`

I try print it out `{{  $username or 'Nothing' }}`

---

## Result

It keep printing `Nothing`

---

## Questions

It seems like my `$username` variable never got sent ?
Can someone please point out what I did wrong here ?

Comment: The problem is likely that `$username` is null or undefined. Try changing `$username` to `"some string"` - I think you'll find that works. And if it does, that means your `$username` variable doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: I know that it's null, I already test my $username variable before I send, and it contain some strings. I just want find out that why it never got sent.

Comment: Actually, I just realized you're doing a redirect, not rendering a view. My answer will be up in a second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redirect is important. From [the documentation on redirects](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects):

> Redirecting to a new URL and flashing data to the session are typically done at the same time. So, for convenience, you may create a RedirectResponse instance and flash data to the session in a single method chain:
>
> return redirect('user/login')->with('message', 'Login Failed');

The thing is, the redirect is handled by the client's browser. In effect the server responds to the first request with "Ok, got your request. Now go to this other URL". And the client then makes the request to the other URL. As such, Laravel cannot just pass values to the next page for rendering, because the client is making a new request. So what the `with()` clause is doing is **flashing data to the session**. So you need to retrieve it from the session when you render the new page.

So what you really want to do is this:

The redirect:

```
return Redirect::to("route1")->with("username", $username);
```

And when the new page loads (possibly at a different route):

```
return View::make("template")->with("username", Session::get("username"));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did : `return Redirect::to("route1")->with("username", $username); `

Comment: Yes, but that is not where the page is being rendered. You're redirecting the user somewhere else.

Comment: I redirect my user to the url : `/` and trying to `{{  $username or 'Nothing' }}` when I am at the url : `/` which is my homepage.

Comment: The point is that the `Redirect::to()->with(...)` is putting data in the session. If you want to do something with that data after the redirect, you need to get it out of the session.

Comment: How to do I do that ? do you mind include that as part of your answer ?

Comment: I have. See the `View::make()` line above? That line renders a template, passing the username (which it gets from the session) to the template.

Comment: I still couldn't get my username to spit out. I'm trying to debug base on your answer. You said "I need to retrieve it from the session when you render the new page." I'm a little confuse. I didn't rediect to a new page. I only redirect to my homepage and that's it.

Comment: You showed us, how to sent in. Can you show us how to retrieve it ? OR show us how to split it out. I'm really curious on what did I do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending Redirect with it stored in temporary session you can check session in view

```
@if(Session::has('username'))

{!!Session::get('username')!!}
 // if you want to keep username session for next view
{!!Session::keep(['username'])!!}
@else
Nothing
@endif
```

read session Doc http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session